# How to send image/Video,Voice Chat using xmpp IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp

I am creating a chatting app using `XMPP`. The text chat functionality is working fine. Now I want to send audio, video and images. Can anyone tell me how to do that? I am using `core data`. It will be better if you guys can suggest me about UI also.

Any samples like WhatsApp are welcome.